# Writing smaller file from larger one - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have a file full of coordinates (doubles), `goog_x0.data` that I can dump partially (using -N) using ubuntu's od

```
 od -tf goog_x0.data -N 128
```

I would like to write a small portion of the file to a smaller file, say file_x_small.data since I am using the file in a program that I want to spend less time reading the file for debugging purposes.

I am not very familiar with Ubuntu. Not sure if I can use some piping technique to accomplish that.

**EDIT**

The following redirect does not work. It seems that it does loose the format somehow.

```
od -tf goog_x0.data -N 128 > test.data

saher@ubuntu:~/MEng/MapD2/tweet-data$ od -tf goog_x0.data -N 128
0000000         14269513.4156659        -6861188.37463115
0000020        -8942359.39085839         11578091.9933553
0000040        -8846995.34718389        -6833842.80406045
0000060                        0        -6517512.40649905
0000100        -8138341.46678531         14435252.4413861
0000120        -8501483.11395763         13296843.7802644
0000140        -7755070.84450014         13470572.3171573
0000160         13473168.0316474        -6639417.40123851
0000200
saher@ubuntu:~/MEng/MapD2/tweet-data$ od -tf goog_x0.data -N 128 > test.data
saher@ubuntu:~/MEng/MapD2/tweet-data$ od -tf test.data 
0000000   1.207373746603704e-153   6.013470016999068e-154
0000020   4.1830098020098914e-62   4.0852372703315125e-33
0000040   6.013470016999068e-154     7.10943601965232e-38
0000060    9.734880952506514e-72    6.004550192158824e-67
0000100    6.01347001699909e-154    2.004167331590866e-52
0000120    6.235846430498795e-38   6.013470017007573e-154
0000140    6.820154117525453e-38    4.672980981722911e-62
0000160   1.3980430905488177e-76   6.013470018395097e-154
0000200   1.3834816647077305e-47   1.3132945355040325e-71
0000220   6.013470574779068e-154    5.885520268567711e-62
0000240   2.5839082398890373e-57   1.3852305828607367e-76
0000260   6.013561551599044e-154   6.013470016999068e-154
0000300   6.013470016999068e-154   6.036777331784069e-154
0000320    9.964234542107476e-48   2.4052552137503745e-57
0000340   1.722587769072365e-259  1.2073748846561837e-153
0000360   2.4737980795715994e-91   3.4593007703033746e-86
0000400    1.087127992907205e-71   6.013470016999068e-154
0000420    1.900984330386797e-52    1.655829109192822e-47
0000440    6.375470807227561e-67    6.01347001699909e-154
0000460    5.933937167156296e-38    9.516918466795852e-43
0000500   6.013470017005542e-154    1.723986684843163e-47
0000520    6.016181036031767e-67    1.398043090568847e-76
0000540   6.013470018395099e-154   2.2150209362279763e-52
0000560    2.109394169858305e-52   6.013470463032317e-154
0000600   3.0574454987539206e-57    1.085575209787513e-71
0000620   1.3852279628540713e-76   6.013561551685871e-154
0000640    4.162976059806925e-62   1.3049067991694336e-76
0000660   6.042735482983213e-154    9.964234542107476e-48
0000700    2.406810962859293e-57   1.398979456465599e-259
0000720   1.316085405819458e-259
0000730
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I used the `split`

```
split goog_x0.data -b 4096
```

and then picked one of the split files as my small file

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the output:

```
od -tf goog_x0.data -N 128 > file_x_small.data
```

Comment: Don't use `od` to view the file.  Instead, try `cat file_x_small.data`.  If you want binary data in the smaller file, then just do: `dd bs=128 count=1 if=goog_x0.data of=file_x_small.data`